# Variable and parameter in a method

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to Python and I have an issue with it when I am creating a function:

I created a dictionary where the keys are parameters like `n_estimators`, `C`, `max_depths` for instance.

I have a loop where I would like to set the parameters for a given estimator (which is an input of my funtion) but I got an issue.

For instance let's say my estimator is a `RandomForestClassifier`,

The code will be:

```
key = 'n_estimators'
estimator = estimator.set_params(key=100)
```

I got the error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter key for estimator RandomForestClassifier.
```

I understand the problem which is that set_params consider key as a parameter (and not as 'n_estimators') but I don't know how to solve the problem yet.

I would really appreciate any advice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dict with the `**` operator:

```
key = 'n_estimators'
estimator = estimator.set_params(**{key: 100})
```

Answer (score 0):

or you know, just

```
estimator.set_params(n_estimators=100)
```

Comment: No I can't because I want to generalize my method for more estimators, I just gave an example with a Random Forest classifier. But my classifier could be an SVM for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `GridSearchCV` to evaluate a model over multiple hyperparameter values, and for different hyperparameters.